# Laravel many to many relation store function

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with many to many relation in laravel

My database is wishlist with tables friends, wishes and wish_friend. My wish_friend table just have wish_id, friend_id and timestamps.

My model is:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Wish;

class Friend extends Model
{
    protected $table = "friends";
    protected $primaryKey = "id";
    protected $fillable = array("name", "age");
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function wishes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Wish', 'wish_friend')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

and this is my controller function create and store

```
public function create() {
    $wishes = Wish::all();     
    return view("friends.create", compact("wishes"));
}

public function store(Request $dados) {
    $friend = Friend::create($dados->all());

    if(is_null($friend)) {
        return redirect()->route("friend.index")->withErrors("Erro ao criar curso. Por favor, tente novamente.");  
    }
    else {
        return redirect()->route("friend.index")->with("Curso inserido com sucesso!");
    }
}
```

this is my friends view create.blade

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')
<div class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Adicionar uma nova curso</h1>
    <h4>Insira toda a informação sobre a curso.</h4>
    <a href="{{URL::route('friend.index')}}" class="btn btn-default">Voltar atrás</a>
    <hr>

    <form action="{{URL::route('friend.store')}}" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" class="control-label">Nome:</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="age" class="control-label">Age:</label>
            <input type="number" id="age" name="age" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="wish" class="control-label">Wishes:</label>
            <select id="wish" name="wish" class="form-control" multiple required>
                @foreach($wishes as $wish)
                    <option value="<?php echo $wish->id; ?>"><?php echo $wish->name; ?></option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Inserir">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
    </form>
</div>
@stop
```

how can I insert in wish_friend when I select wishes?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models this doesn't help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you study [Many to Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) and [Inserting & Updating Related Models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models) you will find other ways to do that:

this is a simple way for your question:

```
 public function store(Request $dados) {
    $friend = Friend::create($dados->all());
    foreach ($dados->wish as $wish) {
        $friend->wishes()->attach($wish);//wishes is the method name that you define in model
    }
    if(is_null($friend)) {
        return redirect()->route("friend.index")->withErrors("Erro ao criar curso. Por favor, tente novamente.");  
    }
    else {
        return redirect()->route("friend.index")->with("Curso inserido com sucesso!");
    }
```

of course you shoud change your form input to array when your input is multiple select **`name="wish[]"`**:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="wish" class="control-label">Wishes:</label>
    <select id="wish" name="wish[]" class="form-control" multiple required>
        @foreach($wishes as $wish)
            <option value="<?php echo $wish->id; ?>"><?php echo $wish->name; ?></option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you help me out with something else?